# opencart custom download file error

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

i am looking to make download files in product page without login or registration in opencart as public download link, after doing the coding am not getting the right download file and also a unknow and unformatted file is downloaded. what i get screnshot

[image]

**model file**

```
        public function getProductDownloads($product_id) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT d.download_id, d.filename, d.mask, dd.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "download d LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "download_description dd USING ( download_id ) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download p2d USING ( download_id ) WHERE p2d.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

    return $query->rows;
    }


        public function getDownload($download_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT d.filename, d.mask, dd.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "download d LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "download_description dd ON (d.download_id = dd.download_id) where d.download_id AND dd.download_id =  '" . (int)$download_id . "'");
return $query->rows;
    }
```

### controller file

```
$data['downloads'] = array();

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDownloads($this->request->get['product_id']);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $data['downloads'][] = array(
                'filename'         => $result['filename'],
                'name'         => $result['name'],
                'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product/download', 'download_id=' . $result['download_id'], 'SSL')
                );
            }




/*download*/
    public function download() {

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        if (isset($this->request->get['download_id'])) {
            $download_id = $this->request->get['download_id'];
        } else {
            $download_id = 0;
        }

        $download_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getDownload($download_id);

        if ($download_info) {
            $file = DIR_DOWNLOAD . $download_info['filename'];
            $mask = basename($download_info['mask']);

            if (!headers_sent()) {
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)) . '"');
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

                    if (ob_get_level()) {
                        ob_end_clean();
                    }

                    readfile($file, 'rb');

                    exit();
                } else {
                    exit('Error: Could not find file ' . $file . '!');
                }
            } else {
                exit('Error: Headers already sent out!');
            }
        } else {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', '', 'SSL'));
        }
    }
}
```

### view file

```
<?php foreach ($downloads as $download) { ?>
<?php echo $download['filename']; ?><br/>
<?php echo $download['name']; ?><br/>
<a href="<?php echo $download['href']; ?>">download</a><br/>
                      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some changes in controller file. I have changed your code. Just replace following code with download function. Hope this could help.

```
public function download() {

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    if (isset($this->request->get['download_id'])) {
        $download_id = $this->request->get['download_id'];
    } else {
        $download_id = 0;
    }

    $download_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getDownload($download_id);

    if ($download_info) {
        $file = DIR_DOWNLOAD . $download_info[0]['filename'];
        $mask = basename($download_info[0]['mask']);

        if (!headers_sent()) {
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)) . '"');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

                if (ob_get_level()) {
                    ob_end_clean();
                }

                readfile($file, 'rb');

                exit();
            } else {
                exit('Error: Could not find file ' . $file . '!');
            }
        } else {
            exit('Error: Headers already sent out!');
        }
    } else {
        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', '', 'SSL'));
    }
}`
```